# Algorithm implementation for ranges support

Tags: c++, std, std-ranges

Looking at algorithms like [`std::ranges::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/upper_bound) I see two implementations:

1. For ranges represented by iterator and sentinel
2. For ranges directly represented by ranges

Is this a kind of legacy or should I implement both versions in order to work with ranges and iterators?

I mean are there situation when client can't convert one to another and use only one interface? Or having two interfaces more convenient than converting on client side?

My understanding is that ranges-based version is natural and the only required for `std::ranges` library while iterator-sentinel-based version is provided only for compatibility reasons for prior iterator-based STL algorithms. Key difference is that ranges-based version should support lazy evaluation with views, projections while iterator-based shouldn’t. Is this correct?

If not, what is the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can both be implemented in terms of the other.

If you had a range and wanted to call the iterator based version, just call the iterator based version with `std::ranges::begin(r), std::ranges::end(r)`.

If you had an iterator-sentinel pair you could call the ranged based version with `std::ranges::subrange(first, last)`.

They are technically redundant. Neither overload supports more or less than the other, e.g. they both can accept ranges that happen to be views.

Generally, the range-based overload just calls the iterator-sentinel pair based overload. I believe the range overload is just provided for convenience, which you should also provide if only to not be surprising.

Comment: With "the range overload is just provided *for convenience*", do you mean "for convenience of algorithm users to avoid aforementioned explicit conversions in code where they are called"?

Comment: @DamirTenishev Yes. Reading historical documents, it looks like the iterator-sentinel overloads were always there and they added quote "New algorithm overloads that take range objects"